# Guidance for using ASP.net MVC as part of SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, asp.net

I am interested in using ASP.Net Mvc 2.0 as the basis for a website but it will need to hook into SharePoint 2007.  Am I just dreaming that it is possible or should I just stick with webforms?

Has anybody used Asp.net Mvc as part of SharePoint 2007?
What problems did you have to overcome to be able to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an MVC SharePoint project on Codeplex here http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/

Here is an article on the subject http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2009/03/17/asp-net-mvc-and-sharepoint.aspx

I havent touched it, and it seems a bit abandoned to me, but it might get you along.

Comment: will a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://aspalliance.com/1944_Using_ASPNET_MVC_2_with_Sharepoint_Publishing. It outlines one method of running mvc with sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Are you connecting your MVC site to SharePoint or are you building something "MVC" on top of the SharePoint server?

Comment: I was hoping to build and MVC site on top of Sharepoint.